# How to reduce the size of index file in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, index, shrink

I am accessing two servers

1. Application server (WC)
2. Database server

The application server is using the database server

Here index file in the database server is growing automatically without any scale. Thus degrading the size and performance of the database.

Please help me for solution. What steps shall I must do for preventing such things?

Comment: What index is that? Why was it created in the first place? How do you know it is decreasing performance?

Comment: Are you possibly talking about the log file as opposed to the "index file"? Can you tell us the name of the file so we can help with terminology?

Answer (score 2):

> Here index file in the database server growing automatically without any scale

By index file, I'm assuming you are referring to the *data file* (typically with a *.mdf or *.ndf file extension)?  There are commonly two types of files within a database:  log files and data files.  Your log file is going to be your transaction log, while your data file(s) will house your data (including your indexes).

As for "growing automatically without any scale", it sounds to me like you are describing autogrowth behavior.  This automatic growth of a database file will happen when there is no longer any space and SQL Server needs *more* space in the file.  If configured and volume free space allow, that file will then grow by a specified amount (either fixed or percentage).

> Thus degrading the size and performance of the database

I'm not sure what you mean by "degrading the size".  It simply makes the size of the database larger.

And as for a performance hit?  Yes, I agree that the actual **operation of growing the file** will have an impact, but the existence of a larger data file in and of itself shouldn't have any perf impact.  If you mean that your data is just getting bigger, and yes that could have an impact on performance, all the while your data file is also growing.

> What steps shall I must do for preventing such things?

If your database files are autogrowing then it is because that space is needed.  So you have two option:

1. Properly size out your database files
2. Minimize the data coming into your database

I'm guessing #2 is not an option, as it usually isn't.  So you just need to size our your data files correctly, ensure there's the right number.  Another common approach is to have a new filegroup (not the PRIMARY filegroup) to house all user objects.  There are more recommendations that simply wouldn't fit in this answer, but it should give you a start on your next step and how you should be approaching this.

Below is a discovery query that will give you the basic outline of your files, and their growth configurations:

```
use AdventureWorks2012;
go

select
    name,
    type_desc,
    physical_name,
    size_mb = 
        convert(decimal(10, 2), size * 8.0 / 1024),
    max_size_mb = 
        case max_size
            when 0 then convert(decimal(10, 2), size * 8.0 / 1024)
            when -1 then -1
            else convert(decimal(10, 2), max_size * 8.0 / 1024)
        end,
    space_used_mb = 
        convert(decimal(10, 2), fileproperty(name, 'SpaceUsed') * 8.0 / 1024),
    is_percent_growth,
    growth_mb_or_perc = 
        case is_percent_growth
            when 0 then convert(decimal(10, 2), growth * 8.0 / 1024)
            else growth
        end
from sys.database_files;
```